# Use java binding of link grammar parser in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, text-parsing, link-grammar

I want to use link grammar parser in my eclipse java project. I have downloaded Link Grammar 5.3.13 from http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/
I have read its README file, but i am unable to understand it.Can anyone provide me with good documentation on how to get on with this parser? 
I have studied this link 
http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/api/index.html
But this gives explanation about code not about the installation.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For a usage example of the Link Grammar Java binding, see [RelEx Semantic Relation Extractor](https://github.com/opencog/relex). Especially, see [LocalLGParser.java](https://github.com/opencog/relex/blob/master/src/java/relex/parser/LocalLGParser.java) there.